# Переопределение save_model для сохранения текущего пользователя

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при создании записи в таблице сохранялся текущий пользователь. Есть класс

```
class SourceHistory(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, verbose_name=u'Источник', null=False, blank=False)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=u'Пользователь', null=True, blank=True)
```

Который в admin.py выглядит так

```
@admin.register(SourceHistory)
class SourceHistoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('source', 'editor')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.editor = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Создание объекта происходит с использованием сигнала post_save

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Source)
def source_save_history(sender, **kwargs):
    source = kwargs.get('instance')
    for f in source.memorized_fields:
        if source.__getattribute__(f) != source.memorized_fields[f]:
            sh = SourceHistory.objects.create(
                source=source
            )
```

Соответственно, сейчас при создании объекта поле editor остается пустым.
Вопрос: как нужно создавать объект SourceHistory, чтобы сохранялся пользователь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текущий пользователь доступен только из запроса, к которому невозможно получить доступ из функционала модели.

В папку рядом с settings.py добавляем файл `middlewares.py` с таким содержимым:

```
try:
    from threading import local
except ImportError:
    from django.utils._threading_local import local

_thread_locals = local()

def get_current_request():
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'request', None)

def get_current_user():
    request = get_current_request()
    if request:
        return getattr(request, 'user', None)

class ThreadLocalMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        _thread_locals.request = request
        return self.get_response(request)
```

В `settings.py` к списку `MIDDLEWARE` дописываем в конец:

`'название_проекта.middlewares.ThreadLocalMiddleware'`

В файле с ресивером добавляем импорт:

`from название_проекта.middlewares import get_current_user`

Сам ресивер теперь будет выглядеть так:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Source)
def source_save_history(sender, **kwargs):
    source = kwargs.get('instance')
    for f in source.memorized_fields:
        if source.__getattribute__(f) != source.memorized_fields[f]:
            sh = SourceHistory.objects.create(
                source=source, editor=get_current_user()
            )
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!